# google maps API: how can I make markers clickable?

Tags: java, android

How can I make markers clickable? On clicking the markers, I need the app to navigate to a different activity.
I have created some markers in a class by taking coordinates from an ArrayList.
Every help is welcome.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Segnalini {

public static void POI(ArrayList<Mostro> Mostri, Marker[] M_Mostri, LatLng[] P_Mostri, GoogleMap Mappa){

    P_Mostri[0] = new LatLng(Mostri.get(0).Latitudine, Mostri.get(0).Longitudine);
    M_Mostri[0] = Mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P_Mostri[0]).title("M1"));

    P_Mostri[1] = new LatLng(Mostri.get(1).Latitudine, Mostri.get(1).Longitudine);
    M_Mostri[1] = Mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P_Mostri[1]).title("M2"));

    P_Mostri[2] = new LatLng(Mostri.get(2).Latitudine, Mostri.get(2).Longitudine);
    M_Mostri[2] = Mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P_Mostri[2]).title("M3"));

    P_Mostri[3] = new LatLng(Mostri.get(3).Latitudine, Mostri.get(3).Longitudine);
    M_Mostri[3] = Mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P_Mostri[3]).title("M4"));

    P_Mostri[4] = new LatLng(Mostri.get(4).Latitudine, Mostri.get(4).Longitudine);
    M_Mostri[4] = Mappa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(P_Mostri[4]).title("M5"));

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleMap mMap = googleMap; // name of your map

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // CONDITION WHEN CLICKED
    return false;
    }
    });
```